# Problem with gnuplot - timestamp data mapping to xrange

Tags: gnuplot, scale, unix-timestamp, xrange

### what i have:

csv data with timestamps in the first column, columns I want to plot selectively after that.
Every data point ist roughly ten minutes apart. Data is for 24 hours. Everything else set up nicely, examples below

### What i want:

Be able to map the time data formatted on the x-axis (xrange?). Like `xtics` every `n` hours, in a given format (like `"%T, %A"`). Best configurable per column I want to plot (thinking about multiplot).

### Data:

```
1545389400,39,0,0,1,664,2493,31.7
1545390000,37,0,0,1,736,3093,32.5
1545391200,33,0,0,1,664,4293,32.6
1545392400,28,0,0,1,704,5493,31.3
1545393000,26,0,0,0,649,6093,30.8
1545393600,24,0,0,0,632,6693,30.5
```

### Code:

```
set title "Battery Log"
set datafile separator ','
set key center bottom outside
set border lw 0.5 lc '#959595'
set terminal svg dynamic rounded mouse lw 1 background '#272822'
set grid ytics
set ytics nomirror in
set yrange [0:100]
set xtics nomirror
set xtics rotate
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%T, %A"
plot 'stats.csv' \
    u 0:2 w l lc '#f92783' t columnheader, '' \
    u 0:8 w l lc '#a6e22a' t columnheader
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you clarify the "what I want" section?

Comment: Sure, question updated!

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
### set time xtics

N = 3  # every n-th hour

set samples 100
set xdata time 
set format x "%a, %H:%M"
set xtics rotate
set xtics N*3600

plot '+' u ($0*1200):(3*sin(x)+rand(0)) w lp pt 7 not
### end of code
```

which should give something like this, ticks every 3rd hour.
Set your `N` depending on the column you want to plot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how does this help me with my code? Could you explain how to adapt this solution to my problem?

Comment: You wanted to have a tic every N hour. So, just use `set xtics N*3600`. I don't know your level of gnuplot and I didn't have enough data to illustrate every 3rd hour, so I had to generate my own dummy data. By the way, you are plotting versus the pseudocolumn 0. If column 1 contains your time data you should `plot 'stats.csv' u 1:2`, see also `help set xdata time`. What do you mean with "configurable per column"? Different time representation or tic distance for a different plot? Just set the timeformat or xtic for each plot differently.